# If $n,r\in \Bbb{Z}^+$ and $2^{r-1}+2-r \leq n < 2^r+1-r$, find $r$ in terms of $n$ in closed form.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For integer $r$ and $n$, consider the relations
$$2^{r-1}+2-r \leq n < 2^r+1-r$$

To eliminate possible pathological cases for small $n$, take both $n$ atnd $r$ to be at least $3$.

I'd like to find $r$ in terms of $n$, in closed form.

I have strong reason to believe that for a given $n$ there will always be a unique value of $r$ satisfying these relations.  That is because
the relations come from an analysis of the number of "is $m$ greater than $k$?" questions might be needed to surely deduce the value of $m$ from among the numbers from $1$ to $n$ numbers, given that you have already been told that $m>1$ and $m \leq 2$, and the person answering the questions **is allowed to lie up to one time**.

$n$ can be considered they are the count (starting at $3$) in a sequence that contains $3$ threes, then $7$ fours, then $15$ fives and so forth.

My attempt:  $$
r = \left\lceil \log_2 (n+\lceil \log_2 n\rceil )
\right\rceil
$$ appears to work up to fairly high $n$, (for example, for $n=27$ this gives $r=5$ but for $n=28$, it gives $n=6$), but I can't show that this always gives the right value.

I suspect that some sort of expression involving an arbitrarily large number of 
$\log\log\log$ type terms will be needed.

Comment: $r=[\log_2 (n+\log_2 n)]+1$ where $[x]$ denotes the largest integer not exceeding $x.$

Comment: I'm pretty certain that for integer $n>1$ this expression is identical to the one I presented. Can you show that this $r$ always obeys the two relations?

Comment: Hint. With $f(r)=2^{r-1}+2-r$ and $r\geq 3$ we have $1<f(r)\leq n<f(r+1)$ so $\log_2(f(r)+\log_2 f(r))\leq$ $   \log_2(n+\log_2n))<$ $\log_2(f(r+1)+\log_2 f(r+1)).$ Compare the far LHS and far RHS to $ r,$ using $ r=\log_22^r$ and the def'n of $f$.